# JTable setValueAt StackOverflowError

Tags: java, swing, jtable, stack-overflow

I've been searching for whole day and I still can't find simple anwser to my problem: **how can I make JTable cell update it's value when I edit it in another one?**

I wanted to use somehow `fireTableCellUpdated` but I don't really understand how can I use it, when and on what object.

What I want is to obtain is some kind of listener that listens whether that values changes or not. In this particular scenario I have editable third column in which I store the amount and I want that listener to automatically calculate and set values in other cells in a row. I've come up with something like this:

```
@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
{
    BigDecimal withoutTax, tax, withTax;

    for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
            BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(table.getValueAt(i, 3)).replace(",", "."));
            BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(table.getValueAt(i, 4)).replace(",", "."));
            withoutTax = amount.multiply(price, new MathContext(2));
            table.setValueAt(withoutTax, i, 5);
            tax = withoutTax.multiply(new BigDecimal(0.23), new MathContext(2));
            table.setValueAt(tax, i, 7);
            withTax = withoutTax.add(tax, new MathContext(2));
            table.setValueAt(withTax, i, 8);
    }
}
```

But this results in `StackOverflowError` and I'm guessing that's because `table.setValueAt` fires `tableChanged` listener so it's going into infinite loop.

**Can someone explain me how can I accomplish that?**

Comment: `tableChanged` is been called when a change to the `TableModel` is taking place, which is been trigged by the `setValueAt` method and around you go...

Comment: The solution?  Do it inside the `setValue` method and trigger a range update

Comment: Hmm, you mean like overriding setValue() in table model? What do you mean by 'range update'

Comment: Pretty much.  What I mean be "range update" is it's probably more efficient to use `fireTableRowsUpdated` to update the entire row in one step, rather then trying to update 4 cells in 4 separate event calls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tableChanged` is been called when a change to the `TableModel` is taking place, which is been trigged by the `setValueAt` method and around you go...

The solution? Do it inside the `setValue` method of the `TableModel`...

```
public class TestModel extends ... { // Some TableModel

    //...

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 3) {
            // Set the value been passed to in (probably from the editor)...            
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
            BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(getValueAt(rowIndex, 3)).replace(",", "."));
            BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(getValueAt(rowIndex, 4)).replace(",", "."));
            BigDecimal withoutTax = amount.multiply(price, new MathContext(2));
            // Set the value for row x 5 directly within the backing store of the model...
            //table.setValueAt(withoutTax, i, 5);
            BigDecimal tax = withoutTax.multiply(new BigDecimal(0.23), new MathContext(2));
            // Set the value for row x 7 directly within the backing store of the model...
            //table.setValueAt(tax, i, 7);
            BigDecimal withTax = withoutTax.add(tax, new MathContext(2));
            // Set the value for row x 8 directly within the backing store of the model...
            //table.setValueAt(withTax, i, 8);
            
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, 5);
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, 7);
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, 8);
            
            // It might actually be easier to use...
            //fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, rowIndex);
        }
    }
```

For example...

This is a basic example, while it only uses a single row, the idea holds true for multiple rows all the same...

[image: Table]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTable table = new JTable(new MultiplicationTableMode());
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

    }

    public class MultiplicationTableMode extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<List<Integer>> values;

        public MultiplicationTableMode() {
            values = new ArrayList<>(1);
            List<Integer> cols = new ArrayList<>(11);
            for (int index = 0; index < 11; index++) {
                cols.add(0);
            }
            values.add(cols);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return values.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return column == 0 ? "?" : "x" + Integer.toString(column);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            List<Integer> columns = values.get(rowIndex);
            return columns.get(columnIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return Integer.class;
        }


        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                if (aValue instanceof Integer) {
                    List<Integer> columns = values.get(rowIndex);
                    int intValue = (int) aValue;
                    columns.set(0, intValue);
                    for (int index = 1; index < columns.size(); index++) {
                        columns.set(index, intValue * index);
                    }
                    fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, rowIndex);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

## Updated...

It occurred to me that if the other column values are not editable, then you don't actually need to maintain their values at all, but can simply calculate them dynamically whenever `getValueAt` is called, for example...

```
public class MultiplicationTableMode extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Integer> values;

    public MultiplicationTableMode() {
        values = new ArrayList<>(1);
        values.add(0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return column == 0 ? "?" : "x" + Integer.toString(column);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        int value = values.get(rowIndex);
        if (columnIndex > 0) {
            value *= columnIndex;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return Integer.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 0) {
            if (aValue instanceof Integer) {
                values.set(rowIndex, (int)aValue);
                fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, rowIndex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, now that explains A LOT I will try it in a minute

Comment: That's the "general" idea ;)

Comment: Hey, wait a minute. That still don't solve the problem **when I trigger that method?** What I mean I would need some kind of `while(true)` loop that checks whether value changed anf if it did then it triggers `setValueAt`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When the cell editor "stops", the `JTable` will call the `setValueAt` method of your `TableModel`, which would then allow you to ascertain the value been updated (the new value for the cell) and then do you secondary calculations, why do you need to call `setValueAt`?

Comment: I guess from two of us it's not you who doesn't understand what's going on. So you're saying it works like this: when I edit a value in any editable cell `JTable` will call `setValueAt`? How could it be? Does it even know which cell did I edit?

Comment: Yes, the `JTable` knows, otherwise, how would it know where to put the editor?

Comment: I've read that every method connected with `JTable` or `TableModel` that has `fire` prefix automatically notifies all 'interested' listeners that something has changed. Is `setValueAt` one of them?

Comment: Yes and no.  `DefaultTableModel` does, but `AbstractTableModel` doesn't, that's what (as you can see in the two examples) I physically call the `fireXxx` methods myself